# How to rename the routing URL of an angular component?

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing, rename

I'm new to Angular and am trying to make some edits in an existing application.

There's a component called `help` in the current application which routes to `mywebsite.com/help`. I wish to change it to `mywebsite.com/contact`.

The `help` component folder has the following files: `help.component.html`, `help.component.scss`, `help.component.spec.ts`, `help.component.ts` and `help.module.ts`.

I tried modifying this part in `general.routing.module.ts`:

```
path: "help", // changed this to "contact"
        pathMatch: "full",
        loadChildren: "./pages/help/help.module#HelpModule",
        data: {
          title: "Help",
        },
```

But it didn't seem to help and I get a **404 error** when I change the path to `path: "contact"` . Can someone please help me where to get started?

There's also another path for help:

```
{
        path: "help-auth",
        pathMatch: "full",
        loadChildren: "./pages/help/help.module#HelpModule",
        data: {
          title: "Help",
        },
      },
```

Do I also need to touch this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Changing the path should be enough. are there any more routing modules with the same path in your application?

Comment: Yes, but with path: "help-auth" as I updated in my post. Do i also need to change this?

Comment: I’m just curious why there are pathMatch: "full" in those routes..?

Comment: Good point :) I'm not sure. I didn't write the original code

Comment: `path: "help"` changing this to `path: "contact"` will work. Re-compile app and re run app, then check out if its working ro not @locke14

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, that's what I tried. But I get a 404 not found error

Comment: curiosity: what version of Angular are you using?  the "loadChildren" has changed from Angular 8, see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: @Eliseo I'm using Angular 7.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was to indeed change `general.routing.module.ts` as below:

```
path: "contact", // changed this to "contact" from "help"
        pathMatch: "full",
        loadChildren: "./pages/help/help.module#HelpModule",
        data: {
          title: "Help",
        },
```

I however forgot to change the html route and so got the 404 error.

This had to be changed from

```
<a class="nav-a" [routerLink]="['/help']" routerLinkActive="a-active">Help</a>
```

to

```
<a class="nav-a" [routerLink]="['/contact']" routerLinkActive="a-active">Contact</a>
```